# How to test a nlp model on a sample having less features (columns) than the training set?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

I was trying to build a NLP model but i got a problem.  After one hot encoding(bag of words), my model has 1500 features but i want to test the model on a data having less features .
How to solve the issue. ?
How to match the presence of the test data words in training data so that i can put zero at other places in the test array and make it of length 1500.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you got it right. But when you are modeling a corpus using **Bags of Words**, you extract a big set of words and have an **array representing** them. Take for example the following "corpus":

- The dog ate food at the market.
- The cat is very furry and cute.

You do some naive *preprocessing* and extract the following features to become your bag of words:

[dog, food, market, cat, furry, cute]

This is the size of your model. When you have some input sample, the sample is then modeled according to your model (will always have the same size). For example:

New sample: "The dog is very cute".

You then extract the features in your model, like so:

{"dog":1, "food":0, "market": 0, "cat":0, "furry":0, "cute":1}

Or, as an array:

[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Therefore, your samples does not have to contain 1500 words or anything like that. Sure, you will have very sparse arrays (lots of zeros a few 1's). Thats where **embeddings** (a.k.a *word2vec* in nlp) come in, but this is another topic.

Now, if your problem is related to input lenght for embeddings, you can use a technique named padding.